# LINQ Query to check BOOLEAN active status

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have a LINQ query as follows:

```
var query = from a in db.ItemMastAltCountries.AsNoTracking()
            join c in db.Countries.AsNoTracking() on a.CountryID equals c.ID
            where a.ItemMastID == _viewfetch.ItemMastID
            orderby a.Name
```

I want to be able to utilize a `boolean` field on the `ItemMastAltCountries` table called `Active`. So the query can also include something like:

```
WHERE Active IN (True, False) OR Active = _viewFetch.Active
```

I want to be able to display all rows (if the are active or not) but on other forms only show the Active rows.

I was thinking along the lines of a ternary operator for this, but not sure if this is the best way to go about it?

Thanks!

Comment: Add the predicate conditionally: `if (_viewFetch.Active.HasValue) query = query.Where(...)`

Comment: First, that's an Entity Framework query, why is it tagged as Winforms? Second, the expected usage makes no sense, the condition is always true. Why don't you just filter by a single filter value, eg ` Active = _viewFetch.Active`? Or are you asking how to dynamically change the filter condition?

Comment: The condition is not always true. EG On a config form I want to see ALL items in a grid no matter the active status, but on a selection or process form I want to see ONLY Active items in a drop down or grid.